# Configure HBase cluster in Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hbase

I would like to configure HBase cluster in Windows environment;

Existing possible ways: **1) Cygwin; 2) VirtualBox; 3) HDInsight;**

My requirement: **Configure HBase cluster purely in windows environment.**

Analysis so far,

1. In file **'hbase-0.98/bin/start-hbase.cmd'** , they have mentioned as below,

   if "%distMode%"=="false" (
     start "HBase Distribution" %HBASE_BIN_PATH%\hbase.cmd master start
   ) else (
     if "%distMode%"=="true" (
        @echo This is not implemented yet. Stay tuned.
        @rem call %HBASE_BIN_PATH%\hbase-daemons.cmd --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" start zookeeper
2. File **hbase-daemons.cmd** is totally missing in the installer package;
3. Message ***"This is not implemented yet. Stay tuned."*** Tells us to wait;

Yet HDInsight and Hortonworks were able to create HBase-Hadoop Cluster in Windows. I would like to do the same;

Please guide me, what configuration do I need to do to configure HBase-Hadoop cluster in windows;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hbasecluster formed on hadoopcluster only.So use normal hbase package.
1.Run zookeeper in system1.here place all PC's ip which are involved in cluster.
2.Then change "start-hbase.cmd" file by using standalone mode command.Then start "Master and Regionserver" in system2.
3.Then start "regionserver" in system3.
4.Now the Hbase_Cluster is ready.